# DialogFragments appear in OnResume()

Tags: android, xml

In my Android app I use quite a lot of DialogFrgaments (and BottomSheetDialogFragments) too.
So, when you click a button, a DialogFragment or bottomsheet appears.
I was multitasking while suddenly, I found a bug in my app, If I have an open dialog, and change to another app, when the app is resumed, a DialogFragment will appear again, it can be even be multiple copies of it.
I need to say that, I dont have any extra code in OnResume.

[This is how it behaves](https://ibb.co/CBvGhQ9)

Comment: Try closing the dialog when leaving the app
Inside onPause() method.
Call the ```dismiss``` method on the dialog.

Comment: @Vishal That actually works, thanks!